# The game is not restarting after the player dies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making this flappy bird replica but instead of a bird it's a rocket.
The controlls are different however the idea is the same.
I have setup a GameManager script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Script Refrences
    public BarrierSpawnner spawnner;
    public MainMen menu;
    public MoveLeft moveLeft;
    public rockeyMovement movement;

    void Start()
    {
        spawnner.StartedGame = false;
        movement.dead = false;
        spawnner.StartedGame = false;
        movement.rend.enabled = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (spawnner.StartedGame)
        {
            menu.menuOn = false;
        }

        if (movement.dead == true)
        {
            spawnner.StartedGame = false;
        }

        if (spawnner.StartedGame == false)
        {
            menu.menuOn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And a Movement Script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class rockeyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Variables
    private float gravity;
    private Vector2 startPos;
    public bool dead;

    // Refrences
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public BarrierSpawnner spawnner;
    public Renderer rend;
    public MainMen menStart;
    public static rockeyMovement Instance { get; private set; }

    void Start()
    {
        Instance = this;
        startPos = transform.position;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        gravity = rb.gravityScale;
        rb.gravityScale = 0;

        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        dead = true;
        gravity = rb.gravityScale;
        rb.gravityScale = 0;
        startPos = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (spawnner.StartedGame)
        {
            rb.gravityScale = 2;
        }
        if (spawnner.StartedGame == false)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }
        

        Vector2 vel = rb.velocity;
        float ang = Mathf.Atan2(vel.y, 10) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, ang - 90f));
        

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * gravity * Time.deltaTime * 1000f);
        }
    }
}
```

As well as a MenuScript:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MainMen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BarrierSpawnner spawnner;
    public GameObject CanvasObject;
    public bool menuOn;

    void Update()
    {
        if (menuOn)
        {
            CanvasObject.GetComponent<Canvas> ().enabled = true;
        }
    }

    public void Go()
    {
        spawnner.StartedGame = true;
        CanvasObject.GetComponent<Canvas> ().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

The game starts out normally in the correct way, the problems pop up the moment the player dies. When the player comes in contact with the obstacles I have the script set a bool to true "dead". And when "dead" is true the menu pops back again however, I you cannot interact with it and the page stays like that.

How do I fix this issue?
Is my logic right?
If not, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't disable Canvas component. Instead, create a panel with buttons on it and activate this panel when needed. Keep it deactivated otherwise.